# $lookup in aggregation working properly in mongo shell command, but while tried by using mongoose node, then getting empty array as response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

$lookup in aggregation working properly in mongo shell command, but while tried by using mongoose node, then getting empty array as response.
I have two collection, and tried to get all records from one collection along with matched record of another collection as part of response objects

mongoose v5.4.6

### Blog collection data sample

```
{"_id":"5d139addce3c200a1416f269","slug":"muthu-xperia","recent_post_title":"muthu","recent_post_desc":"xperia","recent_post_cont":"best","recent_post_trends":"true","meta_keywords":"null","recent_post_img":"http://localhost:3000/upload_resource/276992banner-4.jpg","active_status":"true","status":"true","createdAt":"2019-06-26T16:18:37.941Z","updatedAt":"2019-06-26T16:18:37.941Z","__v":0}
```

### BlogPostComment

```
{"_id":"5d149d61127e78159c67eaee","post_id":"5d139addce3c200a1416f269","post_name":"muthu","post_message":"good afnoon","post_mail":"hiiii@gmail.com","status":"true","createdAt":"2019-06-27T10:41:37.832Z","updatedAt":"2019-06-27T10:41:37.832Z","__v":0}
```

### BlogCol schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const beautifyUnique = require('mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation');
const slugGen = require('mongoose-url-slugs');

// Admin- blog recent post model here
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
recent_post_title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
recent_post_desc: {
    type: String
},
recent_post_cont: {
    type: String
},
recent_post_trends: {
    type: String
},
meta_keywords: {
    type: String
},
recent_post_img: {
    type: String
},
active_status: {
    type: String
},
status: {
    type: String
}
}, {
timestamps: true
});
blogSchema.plugin(beautifyUnique);
blogSchema.plugin(slugGen('recent_post_title recent_post_desc'));
mongoose.model('BlogCol', blogSchema);
```

### BlogPostComment

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const beautifyUnique = require('mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var blogpostmessageSchema = new Schema({
    post_id: {
        type: ObjectId,

        required:true
    },
    post_name: {
        type: String,
    },
    post_message: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    post_mail: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String
    }
},{
    timestamps: true
});
blogpostmessageSchema.plugin(beautifyUnique);
mongoose.model('BlogPostComment',blogpostmessageSchema)
```

### Mongo Shell command working good

```
> db.blogcols.aggregate([{$lookup:{from:'blogpostcomments',localField:'_id',fore
ignField:'post_id',as:'comments'}}]).pretty()
```

### Controller (In mongoose, it's not working )

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Blog = mongoose.model('BlogCol');
const Blogpostmessage = mongoose.model('BlogPostComment');

Blog.aggregate([
    {

            $lookup: {
                from: 'Blogpostmessage', // collection to join 
                localField: "recent_post_title",//field from the input documents
                foreignField: "post_name",//field from the documents of the "from" collection
                as: "postmessage"// output array field
            }

     }
 ],function(err,doc){

     console.log(doc);
     res.send(doc);
 }
 )
```

### Actual Output

```
[ { _id: 5d139ac1ce3c200a1416f268,
slug: 'kumar-note5',
recent_post_title: 'kumar',
recent_post_desc: 'note5',
recent_post_cont: 'good',
recent_post_trends: 'true',
meta_keywords: 'null',
recent_post_img: 'http://localhost:3000/upload_resource/670051banner-5.jpg',

active_status: 'true',
status: 'true',
createdAt: 2019-06-26T16:18:09.419Z,
updatedAt: 2019-06-26T16:18:09.419Z,
__v: 0,
postmessage: [] },
  { _id: 5d139addce3c200a1416f269,
slug: 'muthu-xperia',
recent_post_title: 'muthu',
recent_post_desc: 'xperia',
recent_post_cont: 'best',
recent_post_trends: 'true',
meta_keywords: 'null',
recent_post_img: 'http://localhost:3000/upload_resource/276992banner-4.jpg',

active_status: 'true',
status: 'true',
createdAt: 2019-06-26T16:18:37.941Z,
updatedAt: 2019-06-26T16:18:37.941Z,
__v: 0,
postmessage: [] } ]
```

### Expected Output

```
[ { _id: 5d139ac1ce3c200a1416f268,
slug: 'kumar-note5',
recent_post_title: 'kumar',
recent_post_desc: 'note5',
recent_post_cont: 'good',
recent_post_trends: 'true',
meta_keywords: 'null',
recent_post_img: 'http://localhost:3000/upload_resource/670051banner-5.jpg',

active_status: 'true',
status: 'true',
createdAt: 2019-06-26T16:18:09.419Z,
updatedAt: 2019-06-26T16:18:09.419Z,
__v: 0,
postmessage: [{
    matched record of BlogPostComment model
}] 
},
  { _id: 5d139addce3c200a1416f269,
slug: 'muthu-xperia',
recent_post_title: 'muthu',
recent_post_desc: 'xperia',
recent_post_cont: 'best',
recent_post_trends: 'true',
meta_keywords: 'null',
recent_post_img: 'http://localhost:3000/upload_resource/276992banner-4.jpg',

active_status: 'true',
status: 'true',
createdAt: 2019-06-26T16:18:37.941Z,
updatedAt: 2019-06-26T16:18:37.941Z,
__v: 0,
postmessage: [] } ]
```

Comment: Looks to me like a typo: `BlogPostComment` vs `Blogpostmessage`

Comment: i didn't get you, can you explain it what went wrong

Comment: in your aggregation lookup you refer to a collection called `Blogpostmessage` but you create a collection called `BlogPostComment` - these should match. Try running your queries through the mongo shell directly, and checking the result there.

Comment: i'm new to mean stack. So can you tell need to give model name or collection name

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Blog = mongoose.model('BlogCol');
const Blogpostmessage = mongoose.model('BlogPostComment');

BlogCol.aggregate([
    {

            $lookup: {
                from: 'BlogPostComment', // collection to join 
                localField: "recent_post_title",//field from the input documents
                foreignField: "post_name",//field from the documents of the "from" collection
                as: "postmessage"// output array field
            }

     }
 ],function(err,doc){

     console.log(doc);
     res.send(doc);
 }
 )

Comment: but still i'm getting empty postmessage:[]

Comment: I'm battling with this issue last 2 days, can you give some guidance

Comment: you need to run the aggregation in your mongo console - check that you have documents in both collections, and that the data stored matches their schema precisly.

Comment: I have update both collection sample data at top of question. so kindly look into that

Comment: I tried in mongo shell. but here also i got same empty  response like postmessage:[]

Comment: Now i made change in BlogPostComment  schema and now i got response in mongo shell. but not getting in mongoose. I update schema in above question. Can you see that

Comment: update your question with the exact query you issue to mongo which gives a correct response, and the exact query you issue using mongoose which does not

Comment: yes sure correct, i have update in question

Comment: So now what is wrong with my mongoose code.

Comment: I dont see the query you issue to mongo in your question

Comment: I have update that mongo shell query now. check with that in above question

Comment: great - so use that as your query with mongoose

Comment: blogcols, blogpostcomments are collection name in mongodb. But we use mongoose in nodejs. So here we have model name and as well as get that by mongoose.model('BlogCol');mongoose.model('BlogPostComment') in controller.js. how we use that db collection name here. i confused now

Comment: literally copy and paste the $lookup from mongo, into the $loopup of your aggregate in mongoose

Comment: Even using Mongoose, in the lookup you must reference to the MongoDB collection name so replace `Blogpostmessage` with `blogpostcomments`

Comment: If you want to do it the "mongo" way - take a look at `populate` https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: i check with some entry

Comment: Thanks man @ Zack Newsham, Now i got response in mongoose node also

Comment: I shall post this as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when using mongoose, the names of the collections passed to aggregate operations (e.g., `$lookup`) need to match the exact name of the collection in the mongo database - not the name of the model specified to mongoose.

So, changing your lookup to use `blogpostcomments` instead of `Blogpostmessage` will fix this.

It's also unusual to use a non ID field as a key (either primary of foreign) so it would also be better if your localField was '_id' and foreignField was `postId` - you should also add an index on `postId` if you haven't already done so.

If you want to do this the "mongoose" way - take a look at the populate function, which behaves similarly, but uses mongoose models.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html